# C++: terminate called 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)

Tags: c++, dns

I have a C++ code where I read a string which only contains A,C,G,T

I am trying to find the smallest section(K number) with if I go to the string every section has all four character (A,C,G,T)

When I run the code and enter the string it gives me this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)

Here's the function where i count the K:

```
int counter(string str)
{
int i = 3;
int j = 0;
bool good = false;

while(i < (str.size() - 1) && !good){
    i++;
    while(j < (str.size() - i) && !good){
        string s = str.substr(j,i);
        good = (isin(s,'A') && isin(s,'C') && isin(s,'G') && isin(s,'T'));
        j++;
    }
}
if(i == str.size()){
    cout<<str.size()<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"Smallest section: "<<i<<"\n";
}
}
```

And here's the "isin function"(check if the section contain the character)

```
bool isin(string s,char x)
{
for(int i = 0;i < s.size();i++){
    if(x == s[i]){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

If I understand correctly the error is with the `str.substr(j,i)`

EXPECTED Input and Output: ACCGTTAA -> 6

Comment: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'jo'` in the `counter` function - also, `counter` is declared to return `int` but it doesn't `return` anything so the whole program has undefined behavior. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide compliable code and input , expected ouput.

Comment: I forgot to edit it to good @TedLyngmo

Comment: I added an input and an output on the bottom @gauravbharadwaj

Comment: @NoNameDR You need to turn more warnings on. If you use `g++` or `clang++` add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors` and fix the problems..For example:  `counter` can't be expected to return `6` since it still doesn't return _anything_ so it still has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`str.size()` is an unsigned value, so `str.size() - 1` will wraparound and become a large value when `str.size() == 0`.

You should check if `str.size() == 0` and treat the case separately before the loop.

Also you should use references to strings as the arguments like

```
int counter(const string& str)
bool isin(const string& s,char x)
```

otherwise, the strings will be copied on each function calls and the performance will be degraded.